# Handling when route does not have a resolver in Angular component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

I have a detail component that I am using for both create new and update. I am using a Resolver on the 'edit/:id' route. I am not using a Resolver on the 'new' route.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    if (!(this.route.snapshot.url[0].path === '/new')) {
      this.route.data
      .subscribe((data: { project: Project}) => {
        this.project= data.project;
      });
    }
  }
```

Here are the urls I am able to get. One seems to be the full path and the other seems to be just the last part of the path.

```
this.route.snapshot.url[0].path
// Ends up being: 'new'

this.router.url
// Ends up being '/admin/projects/new'
```

I am trying to figure out if there is a better technique to determine when to load resolver data and when not to. Am I heading in the correct direction using the url? If so which url variable would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

You can use route data to identify whether you are adding a new item or editing an existing one.

In your router:

```
{path: 'admin/projects/:id', component: YourComponent, data: {type: 'edit'}},
```

In your component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.route.snapshot.data['type'] === 'edit') {
        this.route.data.subscribe((data: { project: Project}) => {
            this.project = data.project;
        });
    }
}
```

I can't say that this method is better than using the URLs to identify whether it is an edit or not, but you can use this if you prefer.